# Apache AllowEncodedSlashes Not Working

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts

I'm running Apache(XAMPP package) and i'm trying to allow forward slashes in the URI to be able to retrieve parameters sent with encodeURIComponent, so i added the directive

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
NameVirtualHost *:80
...
```

in httpd-vhosts.conf. however i'm still getting 404 error, am i missing something?

Regards.

Yehia A.Salam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AllowEncodedSlashes can't be put in the `<Directory>` tag and have to put in the root level